# Is there a way to authenticate IMAP using OAuth but keep using the php native functions?

Tags: php, outlook, oauth, office365, imap

So, I have a PHP5.3 application that uses Imap to connect to a Microsoft 365 mailbox. We've always used basic auth for everything. However, starting today, Microsoft doesn't support basic Auth for Imap protocols.

As the system is very complex, I needed to authenticate/connect to my Imap mailbox using OAuth, but keep on using all other PHP native functions.

**Basically I need something that returns the same type of object that imap_open() returns, but using OAuth.**

I really hope something like this exists, thanks for the help!

Here is a list of every PHP native imap function I use on my application:

- imap_open
- imap_fetchbody
- imap_mail_copy
- imap_delete
- imap_expunge
- imap_check
- imap_fetch_overview
- imap_headerinfo
- imap_fetchstructure

Comment: Not sure if you can keep the existing functions, but [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+imap+oauth2) are some likely options for you to pursue to try and get it working. Not sure what you've researched or tried so far, you didn't mention anything.

Comment: I'm dealing with the same problem, what I found so far is the following library that has equivalent functions to native php_imap functions:
https://github.com/javanile/php-imap2